# Iphone development :Is there any way to lock orientation in run time?

Tags: ios, ios4

I need a view that can display both in Portrait and landscape.But when I load another view I only want it show in landscape.

I have a view controller A.which can be shown in portrait and landscape.This view controller is create by the App delegate.

When I click a button on the view A.I create a view controller B which I want to display only in landscape.and load the view like [A.view addSubView:B.view].

When I rotate the device the function shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is called only in
controller A. No matter how I set the function in controller B.It can't be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your first view, make sure that

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {
    return Yes;
}
```

And in your second view set it to

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Update: 
Ok, try this...
In your main view controller/app delegate, where the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is run every time the device rotates, put a global level variable. something like

```
.h
@interface NavAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    Bool *isMain;
}

.m
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    isMain = Yes;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {
    if (isMain) {
        return Yes;
    } else {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
}
// This bit is where you'll have to adapt it to how you change your views
// but it's a basic idea.
-(void)bitThatDoesTheViewChange:(viewController *) controller {
   isMain = No;

   *viewController = controller;

   [viewController release];

   isMain = Yes;
}
```

Comment: I think I've set the function in the second view.But it can't be called.I think only the view controller which is create by the App delegate can override the function

Comment: Added a little more, may help your problem... My ObjectiveC is a little rusty, but I think this should work.